# Let $X$ be a Lindelof, perfectly normal, $\sigma$-space. Must $X$ be separable?

Tags: gn.general-topology, examples

A space $X$ is a $\sigma$-space if $X$ has a $\sigma$-discrete network.

Let $X$ be a Lindelof, perfectly normal, $\sigma$-space.

> Must $X$ be separable?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Defining "$\sigma$-discrete", "network", "$\sigma$-space", etc, would be welcome (a link can be fine if the definition is lengthy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a $\sigma$-space $X$ is Lindelof, then it is paracompact and by Theorem 4.4 of Gruenhage's survey "Generalized Metric Spaces" in the "[Hanbook of Set-Theoretic Topology](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780444865809)", $X$ has countable network and hence is hereditarily separable and hereditarily Lindelof.